# Is there a Python library that allows you to merge duplicate accounts in salesforce?

Tags: python, merge

I would like to merge 10000 accounts who already have a master account assigned to them. This was done on an Excel file manually.
I usually use the simple-salesforce API to update SF records, however it seems to not support the merge option.

Can someone please point me to a Python library that supports this feature?
Much appreciated ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as far as I can tell, there is no Python library that supports this, at least not in the top few Google results (your mileage may vary). You can't use merge in simple-salesforce, because it's a SOAP-based call, at least for now, and simple-saleforce doesn't do SOAP.

Conceptually, you could [export a WSDL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_quickstart_get_WSDLs.htm) and use a [generic SOAP library for Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServices#SOAP) and use the `merge()`. I would advise against it, and go with any of the other popular options that do have this support, such as NodeJS (jsforce), Perl (WWW::Salesforce), or even Apex!

As far as Apex goes, simply create a custom object with two fields, one for the master record, and one for the merged record. Then, write a Batchable class to process those records. Finally, deploy and execute the code. For reference, we did this because we constantly merge duplicates on a daily basis, and it weighs in at about 120 line of code, including additional logging of merge results. You could easily get this under fifty lines of code if you trim it down.